# Text formatting distorted

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019
While Preforming text formatting (CTRL + K + D) everything looks fine except for the style attribute in html document.

Before formatting:

```
<form style="display: flex;flex-direction: column; height: 100%; justify-content: space-between;" [formGroup]="SystemForm">
```

And after:

```
<form style="    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;" [formGroup]="SystemForm">
```

How can i correct that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use popular VSCode extension called **Prettier - Code formatter**, You can also further customise it.

This will format your code as below :

```
<form
  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column; height: 100%; justify-content: space-between;"
  [formGroup]="SystemForm"
></form>
```

Comment: Ohh, Sorry @Idan, This extension is for the Visual Studio Code, I misunderstood. Sorry, let me check other way

Comment: @IdanMarko which version of VS2019 you are using ? there is some bug fixes for inline css formatting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.1,  refer https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/479022/inline-css-formatting.html

Comment: I am using 16.0.4

Comment: Just updated to 16.1.1 and the problem disappeared!

Comment: This might be because they have done fixes in 16.1 as per https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/462140/vs-2019-preview-3-razor-format-document-break-mark.html